# Can schemedraw change fontsize within a label?

Tags: schemedraw

I'd like to use schemedraw to create a PRISMA diagram and want to have a box with a header "HEADER" in one fontsize and some text underneath in a different fontsize is this possible in schemedraw?

For an example of a PRISMA I'd like something like this: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK555520/

The text would be one fontsize and the the (N=***) statement would be another.